# Coming from SQL to EF6 Which loading method should I start with? Lazy Loading, Explicit loading, Eager loading

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading

First question and generic but I haven't found anything to help with this.

I am building a new project with EF6 code first. I understand the differences between Lazy, Eager and Explicit loading. What I am not sure on is which I should start with. ie I am taking advantage of EF & Linq but at what cost later.

Previously I would write a specific SQL query to get a specific set of data. With EF I have a huge amount of flexibility and I am concerned that I could venture down a Loading route but then when I start work on performance and optimisation I might be restricted and/or it may be time consuming to switch loading methods.

**The question is if I start with Lazy Loading and virtual properties how easy is it to manage performance afterwards and switch to more specific loading, or should this be all designed before commencing of the project? Or start with explicit loading, with lazy loading switched off?**

Regards

Comment: My experience: I started with lazy loading as a beginner, then started to use `Include` when perf became unacceptable. Now I almost always write queries manually because I outgrew `Include` as well. The more performance matters to you the less convenience you can have. The more complex and demanding a code-base become the more you're forced to take control.

Comment: Did you find that you could evolve the Data Access and Model easily from Lazy loading or did you find that you had a lot of rewriting or in fact just replace the whole of the Data Access layer? I think I shall carry on with Lazy loading and see how the project evolves anyway as its quick. If this turns out that this was the wrong decision then I learnt something :)

Comment: Often, lazy loading is fine one moment and the next moment you need to do manual querying and rip out all lazy loading stuff. The transition is often sudden and radical. Example: you render a list of questions on a page. Now, you also want to show `question.Answers.Count()` for each question. Lazy loading cannot do that. Now you need to introduce a custom view model and a custom query (`questions.Select(q => new { q.ID, q.Title, AnswerCount = q.Answers.Count() })`). This always happens sooner or later, triggered by increasing business requirements. I usually go directly with the manual query.

Comment: To clarify, there is no well-performing way to solve the example I just gave, except with a custom query. If you didn't query when developing the first version of the project, you might have to tell the customer that this little change (just the added answer count) will cost a lot of money because you now have to rewrite some parts of the page. Inflexibility tends to be costly later.

Comment: @usr, in your question.Answers example, why don't you simply Include("Answers") when you initially query for questions rather than introduce a custom query?  Then you can call question.Answers.Count() to your hearts content without incurring any more db hits.

Comment: @AaronPalmer because that fetches all of the columns. This will likely be a much more expensive execution plan with a key lookup per answer. As I said, the more perf you need the less you can tolerate such inefficiencies. Stack Overflow surely does not load answers using Include.; With Include, you also don't get to filter and sort.

Comment: @usr, what if you made a custom entity for a trimmed down Answer that only included the columns you needed?  Or perhaps when the complexity gets too much you should extract that logic down to a stored procedure and simply map it to a complex type?

Comment: An Include of a collection results in a left join with lots of duplication. Far slower than just fetching a single int. I'm not saying anything against SQL/procs in critical path. That's also a valid solution, forcing you to give up the entity data model and loading.

Comment: @usr could you place your first 3 comments as an answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience: I started with lazy loading as a beginner, then started to use Include when perf became unacceptable. Now I almost always write queries manually because I outgrew Include as well. The more performance matters to you the less convenience you can have. The more complex and demanding a code-base become the more you're forced to take control.

Often, lazy loading is fine one moment and the next moment you need to do manual querying and rip out all lazy loading stuff. The transition is often sudden and radical. Example: you render a list of questions on a page. Now, you also want to show question.Answers.Count() for each question. Lazy loading cannot do that. Now you need to introduce a custom view model and a custom query (`questions.Select(q => new { q.ID, q.Title, AnswerCount = q.Answers.Count() })`). This always happens sooner or later, triggered by increasing business requirements. I usually go directly with the manual query.

To clarify, there is no well-performing way to solve the example I just gave, except with a custom query. If you didn't query when developing the first version of the project, you might have to tell the customer that this little change (just the added answer count) will cost a lot of money because you now have to rewrite some parts of the page. Inflexibility tends to be costly later.

Also, see the comments under the question for further context.

Answer (score 0):

Without an understanding of the system you are trying to build, I would start with lazy loading.  The primary performance issue you should be aware of is the [N + 1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

If you find yourself needing to iterate dependent objects often then consider another solution, such as using Include, or using a separate query to retrieve all dependent objects in a single statement and then joining the two sets in code as needed.

If your system has a focus on reporting then EF may not be the best choice.  Typically reports require many dependent objects to be joined in order to produce the proper output.  Keep in mind that EF is an ENTITY framework, and the properties of an Entity are concerned with CRUD operations, not reporting.

Comment: You have stumbled upon my problem as the project is a combination of the 2, an information/news site with subscriptions and roles ( ideal for EF ) and a large reporting section and management of data, not suited to lazy loading _et al_. and in my head I am trying to use one framework for all. Where actually I should be considering separating out the 2 as EF doesn't fit with reporting as you have said.

Answer (score 0):

A far more important consideration is: how do I manage the **life cycles** of my context instances?

It is common practice to have short-lived contexts. That means: get data, dispose the context and move on. That, in turn, usually means that you want to load the data required for a specific use case within the lifespan of a context. *That*, in turn, means that you will usually use eager loading, and also do everything to prevent lazy loading to get triggered after the context has been disposed (because that would throw an exception).